# In python multiple inheritance without creating object for a class i'm able to get class variable

Tags: python-3.x

```
class A:
    print('class A')
    def __init__(self):
        print('---1')
        print('1')
class B:
    print('class B')
    def __init__(self):
        print('sss')


class C(A,B):
    print('222')
    def __init__(self):
        return 11

class D(B,A):
    print('pp')


d1 = D()
```

I'm getting output:

class A

class B

**222**

pp

sss

Why **222** is getting print without creating an object for Class C.

Comment: You will get a faster response if you use a more descriptive title than "why does this thing happen". See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Remove `d1 = D()` and you'll see that the first three lines are still printed.

This is because unlike function definitions, class definitions are not deferred until the class is constructed. The interpreter instead executes each line as it parses it.